# Very Simple Program Crashing Python 3.5 and spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

```
xx = 0
n = 4294967295

while xx <= n:
    print("xx = ", xx, bin(xx))
    xx += 1
```

This results in the following traceback:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-0c9d04ddbbc6>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Allen/Documents/Python Scripts/crunchy.py', wdir='C:/Users/Allen/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Users\Allen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Allen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Allen/Documents/Python Scripts/crunchy.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("xx = ", xx, bin(xx))

  File "C:\Users\Allen\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 317, in write
    self._buffer.write(string)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: Improve python code style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using ipython.

According to this page: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9168

you might run into a know issue and will be fixed in the next release. By the way, that program does not crash when I am running it in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) This bug is not a Spyder bug but an `ipykernel` bug. It was fixed in `ipykernel` version **4.4**, released in August 2016.

So please be sure to update to the latest `ipykernel` by running this command in a terminal (i.e `cmd.exe`)

```
conda update ipykernel
```