# Closed file error while printing a lot of content to the IPython console in Spyder

Tags: python, range, spyder

My original script is bigger than this, but I discovered this alone causes the exact same error. First post here (I think). So apologies if format not right.

```
for a in range(4000):
    for b in range(200):
        print('4000:' + str(a))
        print('201:' + str(b))
```

And I get all this as errors. I'm Spyder with the Ipython console.

> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/me/Documents/file.py', wdir='C:/Users/me/Documents')
>
> File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/me/Documents/file.py", line 35, in 
>       print('4000:' + str(a))
>
> File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 317, in write
>       self._buffer.write(string)
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: This seems to be an issue with `spyder`'s `execfile` rather than your actual code. Try running it in a non-spyder terminal...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very Simple Program Crashing Python 3.5 and spyder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176831/very-simple-program-crashing-python-3-5-and-spyder)

Comment: Seems to be a known bug in IPython, actually. Are you doing any dark magic with `sys.stdout`, by any chance? What version of Ipython are you using? It may have been fixed in recent versions, and you could try just updating Ipython...

Comment: Yeah. Using command prompt seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Dark magic? Ha. No. Not changed anything if that's what you mean. IPython 4.2.0. But the regular python console also came up with similar problems with Spyder

Comment: Weird. I've used Spyder a bit, and it's a pretty decent IDE, but definitely encountered weird bugs from time to time. BTW, I would upgrade to the IPython 5.x, it is *much* better. Great [new features](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version5.html#ipython-5-0) including live-syntax highlighting, and true multiline editing!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) This bug is not a Spyder bug but an `ipykernel` bug. It was fixed in `ipykernel` version **4.4**, released in August 2016.

So please be sure to update to the latest `ipykernel` by running this command in a terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe`)

```
conda update ipykernel
```

*Note*: It'd be good if you could update to the latest Spyder release too because you're still using version 2.3 and our latest one is 3.1.4.